# Error "Font ptmr8r at 480 not found"

Tags: pdftex

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\usepackage{url}

\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.PNG,.JPG}






\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\title{Test Document}



\end{document}
```

Above is some .tex snippet for testing purpose. When I try to build PDF in MikTex I get an error

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(B:/allcommjp/trunk/NWChemCohpc15/Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for loaded.
(B:\allcommjp\trunk\NWChemCohpc15\IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2012/11/21 V1.8c by Harald Hanche-Olsen and Anders Chr
istensen
-- Based on V1.7a by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/latex\psnfss\ot1ptm.fd")
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
-- This is a 10 point document.
) ("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"))))
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/generic\babel\babel.sty"
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg")
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/generic\babel\english.ldf"
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/generic\babel\babel.def")))
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/latex\cleveref\cleveref.sty")
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex/latex\url\url.sty")
No file Test.aux.
("B:\Program Files\MiKTex\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)

** Conference Paper **
Before submitting the final camera ready copy, remember to:

 1. Manually equalize the lengths of two columns on the last page
 of your paper;

 2. Ensure that any PostScript and/or PDF output post-processing
 uses only Type 1 fonts and that every step in the generation
 process uses the appropriate paper size.

[1

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.EXE (file pdftex.map): cannot open font map file
] (B:\allcommjp\trunk\NWChemCohpc15\Test.aux)Trying to make PK font ptmr8r at 480 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The ptmr8r source file could not be found.

Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font ptmr8r could not be created.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file ptmr8r): Font ptmr8r at 480 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
texify: pdflatex failed for some reason (see log file).
```

Can anybody Help me resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Miktex can't find the pdftex.map. Normally it is created with `updmap --admin` or `updmap`. But why is your miktex in the `B:`-drive?

Comment: @Ulrike: I am using Windows 8.1, may be that's why.

Comment: I have a windows 8.1-pc too and the system is like always in C:. Try to run on a command line `updmap --admin`.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. I installed Miktex using my admin account and it worked fine. Then, I tried pdflatex in another user account and it gave the same errors. I found the answer here:
http://comp.text.tex.narkive.com/EHoYEqh7/pdflatex-can-t-find-font

The summary of the solution is running this command in the same user environment: `initexmf --mkmaps`. It might take some time but it works for me.

Comment: `initexmf --mkmaps` this worked for me.

Comment: for me, it was solved by the explanations in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280631/new-font-file-not-found-with-miktex-installation

Comment: @Jinhua Wang where do you enter the command line initexmf --mkmaps ?

Comment: @user91411I think it is the Mac Terminal

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!!!