# Could not locate a virtual/physical font ecrm1095 during xdvipdfmx run (TexLive installed with install-tl)

Tags: fonts, texlive, xdvipdfmx, texmf.cnf

I am compiling the thesis (using `cleanthesis` style http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) on my [custom](https://github.com/busytex/busytex) (compiled-to-wasm)-xetex.

It fails at `xdvipdfmx` step with errors:

```
xdvipdfmx:warning: Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM "ecrm1095".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> There are no valid font mapping entry for this font.
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Font file name "ecrm1095" was assumed but failed to locate that font.
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output...
```

It wants to run `mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ecrm1095`, but of course it can't because it's running in a browser, and `mktexpk` isn't available.

I read some previous questions on this forum and it seems that the problem is on not running `updmap-sys` or having incorrect `*.map`/`updmap.cfg`/`texmf.cnf`.

Below are details. How do I fix this? Should I add something to my `install-tl` profile so that `*.pk`/`*.vf` files are generated in advance (`install-tl` did indeed run `updmap-sys`)? Is it feasible to do for all fonts storage space-wise?

Thank you!

My TexLive TDS was installed with `install-tl` using the following basic profile:

```
selected_scheme scheme-basic
TEXDIR /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic
TEXMFLOCAL /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSVAR /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-var
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /home/runner/work/busytex/busytex/build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/texmf-config
collection-xetex  1
collection-latex  1
collection-luatex 1
```

In my TDS I do indeed have:

```
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec/ecrm1095.tfm
build/texlive-basic/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/ecrm1095.mf
```

but I do not have any corresponding `*.pk` / `*.vf` files. The `ecrm1095.tfm` file gets discover okay, but then it fails because it can't find the `*.pk` / `*.vf` files.

Here's the full `kpathsea` log (super-long so put it on my gist): https://gist.github.com/vadimkantorov/e8221d479f3c7fa03887418a86ce506f

Here's the `/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg`:

```
# Generated by ./source/texmfrepo/install-tl on Mon Jan  9 13:17:27 2023
# $Id: updmap-hdr.cfg 54473 2020-03-22 10:53:53Z hironobu $
# 
# The updmap.cfg in the TEXMFDIST tree is generated by tlmgr by
# concatenating updmap-hdr.cfg with the updmap.cfg files in this tree.
#
# To make local customizations to the map files, using one of the
# following methods is simplest:
# 1) run
#       updmap-sys --enable Map=foo.map
#    for each map file.  (Or MixedMap instead of Map, if your font has
#    both Metafont and outline definitions.)  See the updmap --help
#    documentation. This will add lines to the updmap.cfg file in
#    TEXMFSYSCONFIG (creating it if necessary).
#
# 2) put all your additional fonts into TEXMFLOCAL, edit
#    TEXMFLOCAL/web2c/updmap.cfg, and run updmap-sys.
#
# See the output of updmap --help and/or
# http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html for more.
# 
# In any case, manual edits to TL's updmap.cfg files, psfonts.map,
# pdftex.map, etc., will be lost on update.  So don't do that.
# 
# The default settings of the updmap options (not maps) are also
# specified in TEXMFDIST/web2c/updmap.cfg (also coming originally from
# updmap-hdr.cfg) and can be overridden by an updmap.cfg in any other
# tree.

# 
# Options for updmap.


# dvipsPreferOutline
#
# Should dvips (by default) prefer bitmap fonts or outline fonts
# if both are available? Independent of this setting, outlines
# can be forced by putting "p psfonts_t1.map" into a config file
# that dvips reads. Bitmaps (for the fonts in question) can
# be forced by putting "p psfonts_pk.map" into a config file.
# We provide such config files which can be enabled via
# dvips -Poutline ... resp. dvips -Ppk ...
#
dvipsPreferOutline true


# LW35
#
# Which fonts for the "Basic 35 Laserwriter Fonts" do you want to use and
# how are the filenames chosen? Valid settings:
#   URW:     URW fonts with "vendor" filenames (e.g. n019064l.pfb)
#   URWkb:   URW fonts with "berry" filenames (e.g. uhvbo8ac.pfb)
#   ADOBE:   Adobe fonts with "vendor" filenames (e.g. hvnbo___.pfb)
#   ADOBEkb: Adobe fonts with  "berry" filenames (e.g. phvbo8an.pfb)
#
LW35 URWkb


# dvipsDownloadBase35
# 
# Should dvips (by default) download the standard 35 LaserWriter fonts
# with the document (then set dvipsDownloadBase35 true) or should these
# fonts be used from the ps interpreter / printer?
# Whatever the default is, the user can override it by specifying
# dvips -Pdownload35 ... resp. dvips -Pbuiltin35 ... to either download
# the LW35 fonts resp. use the built-in fonts.
#
dvipsDownloadBase35 true


# pdftexDownloadBase14
#
# Should pdftex download the base 14 pdf fonts? Since some configurations
# (ps / pdf tools / printers) use bad default fonts, it is safer to download
# the fonts. The PDF files will get bigger, though.
#
pdftexDownloadBase14 true


# dvipdfmDownloadBase14
#
# Should dvipdfm(x) download the base 14 pdf fonts? Since some configurations
# (ps / pdf tools / printers) use bad default fonts, it is safer to download
# the fonts. The pdf files will get bigger, though.
#
dvipdfmDownloadBase14 true


# jaEmbed, scEmbed, tcEmbed, koEmbed
#
# updmap generates a file kanjix.map for usage with dvipdfmx. With this
# option one can switch between not embedding any kanji font, or
# any of the several available. 
# 
# The value can be any string. When updmap is run, the substring
# @jaEmbed@ in a map file name will be replaced with this value, and
# the respective map file used.
#
jaEmbed haranoaji
scEmbed arphic
tcEmbed arphic
koEmbed baekmuk
jaVariant -04


#  (end of updmap-hdr.cfg)
Map      euler.map
MixedMap cm.map
MixedMap cmextra.map
MixedMap cyrillic.map
MixedMap latxfont.map
MixedMap symbols.map
MixedMap cmtext-bsr-interpolated.map
Map lm.map
Map dummy-space.map
Map charter.map
Map fpls.map
Map pazo.map
Map utopia.map
MixedMap rsfs.map
Map usy.map
Map mathpple.map
Map uzd.map
```

Comment: sounds as if the cm-super fonts are not there.

Comment: is this fixable by somehow modifying the `texlive-basic.profile` file that I use for launching the installation process? should I add some collection for fonts in there? `collection-latexrecommended  1`? or is there some smaller command for frequent fonts? e.g. how do I modify it to include fonts from https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/all/texlive-fonts-recommended/filelist? Also, is it possible to somehow ask it to discover the `*.map` files automatically? Thank you!

Comment: no idea, at first I'm on windows and at second I always install a full, vanilla texlive.  But your sty is meant for pdflatex, when using it with xelatex it will use the wrong font encoding and the wrong fonts.

Comment: With `pdflatex` it also fails while looking for another `ecrm*` font, but `pdflatex` just makes less verbose font discovery logs and seems not using `kpathsea`. So I could go back to `pdflatex` after fixing font discovery. I suspect that indeed some `*.map` files are missing, and some `*.profile` modification could fix it, but have no idea how to do that properly :)

Comment: Seems a related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267675/pdftex-error-pdflatex-file-ecbx0800-font-ecbx0800-at-600-not-found, except that here I'm asking how to modify the `*.profile` file. I'll try using `\usepackage{times}`, but still having some explanation on fixing EC fonts would be good

Comment: Another question: Is there a way of installing fonts / discovery of `*.map` files by just extracting an archive without modifying the `updmap.cfg`? I have to split the parts of TDS into several archives of max. 100Mb, but I can't run `updmap-sys` in the browser (in theory I could, but it would very-very much simplify things if I don't have to deal with it)

Comment: you could install a local (full) texlive and then copy the generated map files from texmf-var/fonts/map. But do you actually have the fonts? That means have you a folder `\texmf-dist\fonts\type1\public\cm-super` with lots of pfb in it?

Comment: Are normally the `*.pk`/`*.vf` files generated at the `install-tl` time? Or on-the-fly at the first usage?