# Why, since today, Bitmaps fonts are used?

Tags: fonts

My question is similar tho those but different:

- [The text in pdf is not smooth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205578/the-text-in-pdf-is-not-smooth)
- [Why are Bitmap-Fonts used automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically)

Since **today**, as of question title, my pdf looks bad, because of Bitmap fonts. Until few hours ago I never seen a bitmap font in this paper I'm working on since few months (the first paper I write in LaTex so please be patient).

What happened today: I added a bibliographic entry to a database (managed with JabRef) and after that I had problem building. I tried several thing such as cleaning temporary files and so on. I installed the latest, new version of TeXstudio. I finally removed MiKTeX and reinstalled from a local repository I created few days ago and from where I had reinstalled MiKTex few days ago. This last step finally solved but introduced the problem of Bitmap fonts.

Following the steps of the related question, installing package `cm-super` and so on apparently solve the issue, but I'm concerned because I neved had to do this and I never had the problem of Bitmap fonts.

From what I understand using `cm-super` is not without consequences and so, I wish to avoid this workaround to a problem I never had.

This is the most simple document that show the problem.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
This is a test
\end{document}
```

[image]

System: Windows x64

The log file show an error:

> pdflatex.exe (file pdftex.map): cannot open font map file] (test.aux) )
>     Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: 207 strings out of 493634 
>     2132 string characters out of 3142147 52604 words of memory out of 3000000

Comment: It's notorious that MiKTeX has some problems with CM-Super and also other fonts: it somehow chokes when it has to rebuild the map files. There are just a few rarely used fonts that are available only in bitmap format.

Comment: Really MiKTeX has no problem when I install CM-Super. The question is why now I'm required to install it if until few hours ago all was working fine without installing it...

Comment: The document you are showing doesn't use T1-encoding and so doesn't use the cm-super-fonts. Beside this: nobody can know why cm-super was missing / not used after your reinstallation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Should I be able to get non-Bitmap fonts with this simple document that don'use T1-encoding and so don't need CM-super fonts witout installing CM-super fonts?

Comment: Yes, in a default installation such a document uses scalable fonts. But it is possible to change this, and also normally you should use T1-encoding. If you don't want to use cm-super, use lmodern.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I don't understand. What can I check/change to make my simple document uses scalable fonts and without installing cm-super o lmodern?

Comment: Show the log-file of the compilation of the simple document. Does it really use bitmaps?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "Cannot open font map file"...

Comment: run on the command line `updmap`. Does this help?

Comment: I was just seaching on the net about this error and I found a related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280631/new-font-file-not-found-with-miktex-installation; I followed this but didn't help when I run as admin... running updmap as user helped (I also clen some cache)!

Comment: Again this problem, today, on another new computer... and again the "solution" was `updmap`/`mkmaps` as not-admin...

Answer (score 1):

Run with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapfile{lm.map}% use only Latin Modern as vectorfont
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\scalebox{15}{O} % Computer Modern -- Bitmap
    \fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\scalebox{15}{O} % Latin Modern    -- Vector
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% use always vector fonts if available
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\scalebox{15}{O} % Computer Modern -- Bitmap
    \fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\scalebox{15}{O} % Latin Modern    -- Vector
\end{document}
```

Using Latin Modern by default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% use always vector fonts if available
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem, apparently was not related to a `cm-super` vs `lmodern` issue. As of "chat" with @UlrikeFisher, that didn't posted an answer, I had to run `updmap` _as user_ to solve, without the need to install `cm-super` or using `lmodern`.

Comment: `lmodern` is installed by default. And it is available with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` . Running `updmap` is only needed when installing an additional font like `cmsuper`

Comment: I didn't install `cm-super`, and I do not use `lmodern` (I think). After running `updmap` I don't experience the problem any more. I do no why the problem appeared and I do no why this solved.